# Quota for UrlFetchApp fetchAll

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I use AppScript for Google Sheets. And want use fetch. Question:

This one command:

`UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([req1, req2, req3])`

It is one call or three calls for Quota Google Services?

Comment: This:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: There's no official documentation regarding this, but easiest way is to test a dummy url 20k times .

Comment: If the specification is not changed yet, in my experience I investigated before, `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([req1, req2, req3])` uses 3 quotas.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tanaike has stated every request inside [`fetchAll()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)) counts for the quota.

Meaning that if you have 3 request inside `fetch` it would could as having made 3 different `fetch`.